# What are the trivial operations in std::is_trivially_copy_constructible in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Here's an excerpt from the documentation of std::is_copy_constructible (1) and [std::is_trivially_copy_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible) (2) on [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com):

> 1) Checks whether a type is CopyConstructible, i.e. has an accessible
>   explicit or implicit copy constructor. If the requirement is met, a
>   member constant value equal true is provided, otherwise value is
>   false.
>
> 2) Same as (1), but the copy constructor expression does not
>   call any operation that is not trivial.

So what is considered a trivial operation here?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) may help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This quote from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/46642) explains it:

> > A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided and if
> >
> > — class X has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> >
> > — the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> >
> > — for each non-static data member of X that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor
> > selected to copy/move that member is trivial;
> >
> > otherwise the copy/move constructor is non-trivial.
>
> Basically this means that a copy or move constructor is trivial if it
> is not user-provided, the class has nothing virtual in it, and this
> property holds recursively for all the members of the class and for
> the base class.